# WPF: Inner content wont scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll, scrollviewer

I have a Window with a Grid inside:

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="70" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding ChildViewModel.View}" />

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding SearchResultViewVisibility}">
        <GridSplitter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="LightGray" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTabStop="False"/>
        <Views:SearchResultView DataContext="{Binding SearchResultViewModel}" />
    </DockPanel>

    <UserControls:GradientBackgroundControl Grid.Row="2" Height="25">
        <Validators:FocusSummaryControl x:Name="FocusSummary" ValidateOnlyFocusedElement="False" />
    </UserControls:GradientBackgroundControl>
</Grid>
```

The ContentControl gets a UserControl with this Grid set:

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <StackPanel>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem now is, that the ScrollViewer in the UserControl doesn't scroll. The content of the UserControl set to the ContentControl is heigher and the overflow ist just hidden.

Comment: Does it behave more like you expect if you change the height of the first row of your `Grid` to something other than `Auto`?  e.g.: `<RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="70" />`

Comment: It really makes a difference, but the height is then unchangeble. So the UserControl takes just its height needed on initialization and doesn't grow at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, StackPanel requires a Height to be set for scroll functionality to work because StackPanel, by design, grows in one direction (based on Orientation).

To confirm whether this is the cause of your problem, please test by setting the height of StackPanel to a fixed height. Alternately, you may want to replace the StackPanel with say DockPanel and see the behaviour. Also there is a ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll property that you may want to fiddle with.

Let us know the result of this test.

Comment: Setting MaxHeigh of the ScrollViewer did it, but it would be better the ScrollViewer would just stop growing, when the window does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rearrange things a little bit.  My suggestions (I'm sure there are infinite variations that would work):

First, add a new row to your grid (`Height="Auto"`) and set the height of your top row (with your `ContentControl` in it) to `"*"`

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="70" />
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="25" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Second, move your `GridSplitter` out of the DockPanel.  Put the splitter in row 1 and the dockpanel in row 2.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding ChildViewModel.View}" />

<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTabStop="False" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>

<DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding SearchResultViewVisibility}">
    <Views:SearchResultView DataContext="{Binding SearchResultViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Note that you'll probably also have to set the `ResizeBehavior` for your GridSplitter as shown above.  I hope this will get you close to what you want.